# SVN Subversionのexport(trunkとbranchの違い?)

Tags: svn

どなたか教えてください.
linuxサーバーのsubversionとwindowsのtortoisesvnを使用しています.

rev
100 hoge.txtとfoo.jpg修正
99 hoge.txtとbar.doc修正
98 hoge.txtとfuga.png修正
97 hoge.txtとfoobar.txt修正

上記のようなコミットがあったとき,
リビジョン97,98を指定して,下記のように3つのファイルを一括してexportしたいんですが
なぜか最新(rev100)のhoge.txtがexportされます.

hoge.txt rev98状態がほしいが最新のrev100になり困っている
fuga.png rev98状態
foobar.txt rev97状態

以前branchで作業していた時は意図したrev98のhoge.txtになった気がするんですが,
最近trunkで作業するようになってからrev97,98を指定してもrev100のhoge.txtが
exportされるようになった気がします.
trunkでは常に最新のリビジョンがexportされる、という仕様なんでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

書かれている情報からは断定できませんが、サーバ上のファイルが一部破損している可能性が考えられます。私も最近似たような状態を体験して痛い目にあいました。

一見正常にチェックアウトできているように見えるのにコミットできなかったり、特定のバージョンしかチェックアウトできなかったりしている場合、サーバのファイル破損を疑ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

可能であれば保存してあるバックアップから別のマシン上にリポジトリを再構築して、どこまで正常にアクセスできるかを何世代かにわたって調査してみることをお勧めします。